# Reemplazar ciclo For en php

Tags: php, api

Tengo que realizar una consulta a una API de unos productos, todo lo debo de guardar en un array.
desde la API tiene control para que solo se permita consultar 30 productos, por lo que realice un ciclo para realizar la petición cada 30 productos.

actualmente lo tengo que sea menor que 400 y que se sume 30

```
 for($i = 0; $i <400; $i+=30){
       
    
// Conexión API origen
// ===================
    echo "➜ Contador ...".$contador." \n"; 
    $url_API="https://api.xxxx.com/api/v1/items?start=".$contador;
            
    //token de la app
    $token = "blablablablblabla";

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: '.$token;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_API);//url de la app 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);// parametros del header
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20); // tiempo de espera para la conexión
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);//autorización para realizar consultas
   
    $items= curl_exec($ch);
    $items = json_decode($items, true);
    
     foreach($items as $item){
        // var_dump($item);
        array_push($items_pos,$item);

    }

    $contador=$i+1;
}
```

pero así queda muy restringido, dado que se pueden crear mas producto, y puede superar los 300 productos.
me tocaría modificar el código cada vez que incrementa el numero.

hay alguna forma de hacerlo que sea automatico?
He leido y creo que el While me funcionaria, pero, en la estructura que he visto, tambien se le envía como paramentros el numero.

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 10) {
    echo $i++;  /* el valor presentado sería
                   $i antes del incremento
                   (post-incremento) */
}
```

No se muy  bien, como realizar este proceso. como lo planteo

Comment: Primero que nada... debe haber un tope, es decir, debes definir bien la condición de salida si quieres usar un `while`. Mismo caso con `for`, ambos se comportan del mismo modo, lo que te está complicando acá, es tu condición de salida. Por ejemplo... ¿Como puedes saber cuantos productos se crearon en total?

Comment: Ese es precisamente el lio que tengo, como apenas estoy realizando la consulta no se en si cuantos productos hay en total, porque bueno, si pudiera saber cuantos productos existes antes de realizar el ciclo, puedo incluir la propiedad count, pero el problema es que por restricciones, solo me deja consultar 30 productos, por eso es el ciclo.

Comment: No, por lo que te indico que solo permite consultar de a 30 productos. :( por restricciones de ellos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que no se puede saber cuantos `productos` existen, entonces, podemos usar el paginado y el resultado obtenido para determinar cuando dejar de buscar, por ejemplo:

- Si `$items` tiene menos de `30` productos, significa que esta es la última página.
- Si `$items` tiene `30` productos, significa que hay que ver la siguiente página.
- Si `$items` esta vació, significa que la página anterior era la última

Teniendo en cuenta estas condiciones, tu código podrías ser así:

```
<?php

$items_pos = [];
$contador = 0;
while (true) {

    // Conexión API origen
    // ===================
    echo "➜ Contador ..." . $contador . " \n";
    $url_API = "https://api.xxxx.com/api/v1/items?start=" . $contador ;

    //token de la app
    $token = "blablablablblabla";

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: ' . $token;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_API); //url de la app 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); // parametros del header
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20); // tiempo de espera para la conexión
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //autorización para realizar consultas

    $items = curl_exec($ch);
    $items = json_decode($items, true);

    // Controlamos si devolvió registros
    if (empty($items)) break; // No hay mas items, cortamos el while

    // Incrementamos el contador para obtener los siguientes registros
    $contador += count($items);

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // var_dump($item);
        array_push($items_pos, $item);
    }
}
```

**PD**: No estoy seguro si `$contador` debería empezar en `0` o en `1`. Por otro lado me inclino a pensar que el código original estaba mal al hacer `$contador=$i+1;`

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona correctamente. mil gracias de nuevo por tu gran ayuda